# C recv() continues reading even though socket is empty

Tags: c, sockets

New to Socket Programming. I was making a HTTP server. In the persistent connection, I keep the socket open after the server has sent the first file (1 MB text file) for the 1st HTTP request from the client. After that the server and client programs just sit idle. I have searched a lot and found that recv() keeps looking for data on the socket until the socket connection closes from the server side.

What Should I do in case of a persistent connection?
I am reading a file at the client side (File contains many lines. On each line there's just a file name, that is to be fetched from the server via a persistent connection)

Part of Server code which send the file requested:

```
while((bytesread = fread(filecontent,sizeof(char), 1024, fp))>0)
{
    printf("Bytes Read:%d File Content:%s\n",bytesread,filecontent);
    if((n = send(*newsockfd, filecontent, 1024,0))<0)
    {
        error("SERVER Error: Failed to Write File to Socket");
        break;
    }
    bzero(filecontent,1024);
}
```

Part of client code where I read the file that has been sent by the server:

```
for(;;)
{
    n=recv(socketfd, buffer, 1024,0);
    printf("%d\n",n);
    if(n>0)
    {       printf("\n in while for reading the file for n bytes %d \n",n);
            printf("Response:\n%s",buffer);
    }
    else if(n<0)
    {
            disperror("Error reading from socket");
    }
    if(n==0)
            break;
}
```

Have spent a lot of time. Could not get what to do...

Comment: Did you call `connect` in the client part of code ???      Before `recv`.

Comment: First of all, you need to `send` up to `bytesread` bytes, not hard-code `1024`.  As for your question, is the issue that you don't know when to "hang up" and stop trying to receive data, or...?

Comment: and i don't like this place `if((n = send(*newsockfd, filecontent, 1024,0))<0)`. You use pointer to the socket `newsockfd`??? Please, put here declaration of `newsockfd` variable.

Comment: yes called connect before recv.

Comment: Yes will be sending bytesread. yes don't know when to stop trying to receive data. I read that recv() just keeps looking for data on the socket. So even after the server has sent all 1MB text the client side recv() keeps looking for data on the socket.

Comment: uh actually, newsockfd's address is what I'm passing to another function where I'm writing data. Yes can change that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your client-server protocol is insufficient.  The server sends all the bytes of the input file (and more, because you hard-coded `1024` instead of using `bytesread`).  But how should the client understand when the file is complete?

One easy solution is to have the server begin each transmission with the file size.  You can simply send a `uint64_t` (not `int` because it must be a fixed size on all platforms).  That number will represent the total bytes to follow (i.e. the file size).  You can get the file size using `fseek` in the usual way (`SEEK_END` then `ftell` or similar).

Then, once your client has received the specified number of bytes, it can break out of the loop.

Comment: Uh actually I was sending bytesread. Then was playing around with the hardcoded value. Neither of those worked... Yes I get what you're saying, sending the file size...Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> continues reading even though socket is empty

'Socket is empty' is meaningless. It is either open or closed. In this case it is still open, so your code keeps reading. It will only stop when the peer closes the connection.

If you're going to implement HTTP you need a good working knowledge of [RFC 2616](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt), especially the parts relating to content length. Your code doesn't begin to address that currently, and it's too brodpad a topic to cover here. Uffice it to say that keepalive and reading a socket to end of stream are mutually inconsistent.

NB if you get an error reading a socket other than `EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK` you should exit the loop, and you should also print the real error, not some message of your own devising.

NB (2) You don't need to zero the buffer.

NB (3) The correct way to print the buffer is `printf("%.*s", n, buffer)`, but only if `n > 0`.